# How to remove escape characters from string in python?

Tags: python

I have string that look like this `text = u'\xd7\nRecord has been added successfully, record id: 92'`. I tried to remove the escape character `\xd7` and `\n` from my string so that I could use it for another purpose.

I tried `str(text)`. It works but it could not remove character `\xd7`.

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xd7' in
>   position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Any way I could do to remove any escape character as such above from string? Thanks

Comment: do you use Python 2 ? Did you try to encode/decode it using ie. `Latin1` or other encoding ?

Comment: if you don't need first char then simply slice it  - `text = text[1:]`

Comment: @furas, yeah my python version 2.7. I have tried other encoding as `literal_eval(text)` but still does not work. Thanks

Comment: I means `text.encode('latin1')`

Comment: \xd7 is the unicode character for latin 'x'. You can encode it using 'latin-1' and decode it. `enc = text.encode('latin-1') enc.decode('latin-1')`. This will convert \xd7 to 'x'

Comment: @nag yes, I have tried it but it still the same error "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xd7' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)" thanks

Comment: I tried it and its working. `text = u'\xd7\nRecord has been added successfully, record id: 92'
enc = text.encode('latin-1')
enc.decode('latin-1')` and the output is `'×\nRecord has been added successfully, record id: 92'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have a unicode string like in python 2.x we have unicode strings like

inp_str = u'\xd7\nRecord has been added successfully, record id: 92'

if you want to remove escape charecters which means almost special charecters, i hope this is one of the way for getting only ascii charecters without using any regex or any Hardcoded.

```
inp_str = u'\xd7\nRecord has been added successfully, record id: 92'
print inp_str.encode('ascii',errors='ignore').strip('\n')

Results :  'Record has been added successfully, record id: 92'
```

First i did encode because it is already a unicode, So while encoding to ascii if any charecters not in ascii level,It will Ignore.And you just strip '\n'

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: it works just like expected to remove ascii characters, I checked for an answer among other answers because here it keeps other punctuation marks :). Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following using replace :

```
text=u'\xd7\nRecord has been added successfully, record id: 92'
bad_chars = ['\xd7', '\n', '\x99m', "\xf0"] 
for i in bad_chars : 
    text = text.replace(i, '') 
text
```

Comment: does `bad_chars = ['\xd7', '\n', '\x99m', "\xf0"]` can cover every escape characters because I would like it smartly to escape every of those if meets any? Thanks

Comment: I thought you just have a few bar_chars to remove. In this case, maybe the other solutions will work using Regex.

Answer (score 0):

I believe **Regex** can help

```
import re
text = u'\xd7\nRecord has been added successfully, record id: 92'
res = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', ' ', text).strip()
```

Result:

```
'Record has been added successfully record id 92'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by 'slicing' the string:

```
string = '\xd7\nRecord has been added successfully, record id: 92'
text = string[2:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `regex`.

```py
import re
def escape_ansi(line):
    ansi_escape =re.compile(r'(\xd7|\n)')
    return ansi_escape.sub('', line)

text = u'\xd7\nRecord has been added successfully, record id: 92'
print(escape_ansi(text))
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the built-in regex library.

```
import re
text = u'\xd7\nRecord has been added successfully, record id: 92'
result = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', ' ', text)

print(result)
```

That spits out `Record has been added successfully record id 92`

This seems to pass your test case if you can live without the punctuation.

Comment: yeah exactly, how possibly I could preserve the punctuation marks? Thanks

Comment: Can it just be specific punctuation or must it be all punctuation in general?

Comment: It could be all in general, I could not predict. as this case, my punctual symbol `:` was striped out. Thanks